# Enable Strict Error Reporting in PHP 5.4.4

Tags: php, session

I work on a localhost. I have php 5.4.4. I Just read on php.net that since version 5.4 onwards E_STRICT became part of E_ALL.

So, i see in my php.ini file this.

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

So, i assume, it is the strictest Error reporting mode. So, i make a mistake intentionally to see if this works.

I set $_SESSION key to begin with a numerical value in my code. No error is reported. The program simply runs incorrectly.

I have also set: `display_errors = On`

So, i assume any error shall be reported in my browser, when the script is run. But, nothing happens.

One of the Fellow, Stackoverflow.com Members, was checking my code and found out the error, because his browser reported the error. But, nothing happens in mine.

Comment: Whatever fixed your problem (you should have used an array as value in the first place, but that's another story), the arguments given were wrong. Based on that wrong information you're testing the wrong things and then ask the wrong questions ;) Whatever you read in the internet, do not trust it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have your PHP configured to not output errors to screen, rather logging them to a log file.

That is, you have [display_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) set to `false`, and [log_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) set to `true` .

That is the common configuration for production websites, not echoing errors to screen (which could reveal important info for an attacker) but writing them to the web server log.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you install a global error handler, and do some formatting there, to get a nice result:

```
  set_error_handler( 'error_handler' );

  function error_handler( $errno, $errmsg, $filename, $linenum, $vars )
  {    
    // error was suppressed with the @-operator
    if ( 0 === error_reporting() )
      return false;

    printf( "Unrecoverable error in `%s' line %s: %s\n\n", $filename, $linenum, $errmsg );

    exit( $errno );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a bit hard to track. If you want to see the actual error message with display errors, you have to keep the following in mind:

The [`display_errors` directive](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) works only as long as there is some display it could output to.

Normally the session is saved on disk at a time when your script has already finished and there is no output associated any longer to it.

Therefore you can not make the following notice visible with that setting:

> Notice: Unknown: Skipping numeric key 0 in Unknown on line 0

The *in Unknown on line 0* is a sign that this is not the normal PHP code. It's just when the PHP engine shuts down and saves the session data.

So you can *never* get this error message onto your display *unless*:

- You track the error log or use the CLI environment which still has an output in shutdown phase (STDOUT)
- You use `session_write_close()` to write the session while your script still runs:

> Notice: session_write_close(): Skipping numeric key 0 in ... on line 12

Hope this helps and clarifies it fully.

Comment: The thing is, my issue was solved as soon as i swtiched to a session key starting with an alphabet.

Secondly, the error i want to be reported is not showing up with `error_reporting(-1);` as well.

Comment: @RohitTripathi: I could now fully reproduce the problem and added you an explanation. That should give you an explanation. Session keys can not be numbers only (well actually they can, I've seen that but current PHP seems to prevent it) but they still can start with a number is some non-number character follows. My fault, I didn't know how to reproduce it.